# Getting 404 from WCF webservice over HTTPS

Tags: wcf, web-services, https, http-status-code-404, wcf-binding

I've been having fun and games dealing with WCF over SSL and load balancing :(

Current stand point is that it would seem we get to the server but it doesnt like the end point in thbe config.

Can any one advise?

Client config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkflowAPI" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://ourserver.com/API/workflow.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkflowAPI" contract="Warms.IWorkflowAPI"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkflowAPI" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Webservice web config.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="Originator Secured">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" />
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="xx.xx.Web.UI.API.Workflow" behaviorConfiguration="Originator Secured">
      <endpoint address="https://ourserver/API/workflow.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkflowAPI" contract="xx.xx.Web.UI.API.IWorkflowAPI"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkflowAPI"  listenUri="/" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
           <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkflowAPI" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="Workflow API Binding">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="CustomHttpBinding">
        <security allowInsecureTransport="True">
        </security>
        <httpTransport />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What does http sniffer, like fiddler is showing? I know you'll not be able to see the contents because of https, but you should still be able to see headers

Comment: The error I get is  "There was no endpoint listening at https://ourserver.com/API/workflow.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: The inner exception is 
"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Comment: Is condtract the same between client and server? Can you generate a new service reference?

Comment: Yes, I can generate a new service referrence.

Comment: Not sure if this is solution per se but, one way round the problem is to use s tunnel to simply re-encrypt back to SSL.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your load balancer is not using SSL for its connection to the real web servers. Once you enable transport security your WCF service won't respond on port 80, only on 443.
I think your options are:
1. to have the load balancer renegotiate SSL between itself and the web servers
2. leave transport security off in your WCF config and use only message security, leaving SSL for the load balancer to do.

Comment: Close...the load balancer was taking the https request and stunneling it to http then going to server.  Sorted that by doing another stunnel.